# JGIT AddCommand not adding anything to my github repo

Tags: java, git, jgit

My Java program saves a json file to a directory and I want to then add that json file to a separate gitrepo but the JGIT AddCommand doesn't seem to be working for me.

What is working:
Cloning.
Checking out branch.
Committing.
Pushing.

It successfully pushes to the gitrepo but it says 0 changed files 0 additions 0 deletions.

```
 File file = new File("./config/generic/some.csv");

    if (file.exists()) {

            logger.info("file exists");


            AddCommand add = git.add()
                    .addFilepattern("./config/generic/some.csv");

            add.call();

            logger.info(add.getRepository().getIndexFile());

            CommitCommand commit = git.commit();
            commit.setMessage("Commit Ingestion Output").call();
            logger.info(commit.getRepository());

            //tells the file differences
            DiffCommand difference = git.diff();
            difference.call();

            PushCommand push = git.push();
            push.setRemote("origin").setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).call();
    }
    else{
            logger.info("file doesnt exist");
        }
```

I though maybe this is a .gitignore problem but I cant find that file anywhere. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does the file actually exist, ie.e do you see `file exists` in the log? Besides that, the path given to `addFilepattern` must be relative to the root of the repository working directory.

Comment: Yes, the logs say "file exists" and yes, it is referencing to the root.

Comment: This would mean that the current working directory is the root of the repository working directory, you sure? If so, omit `./` in the path passed to `addFilepattern`.

Comment: Dang it... I made a dumb mistake along the lines of what you said. Thanks for the Help!